# Build transition between clips AVMutableComposition

Tags: macos, avfoundation

I'm using the following code to build an AVMutableComposition that simply transitions between clips. It works fine when I have an array of two clips, but when I add a third, the video is blank (even though the audio seems to work fine). Any advice?

```
- (AVPlayerItem *)compositionFromPlayerItems:(NSArray *)playerItems
{
    NSMutableArray *transitions = [NSMutableArray array];
    AVMutableComposition *composition = [AVMutableComposition composition];
    AVMutableVideoComposition *videoComposition = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];

    CMTime transitionDuration = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(5.0, 600);

    CMTime startTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.0, 600);

    AVPlayerItem *itemOne = playerItems[0];
    AVAsset *videoAssetOne = [itemOne asset];
    AVAssetTrack *videoAssetTrackOne = [videoAssetOne tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo][0];
    AVAssetTrack *audioAssetTrackOne = [videoAssetOne tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio][0];
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *trackOne = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *audioTrackOne = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

    NSError *error = nil;

    [trackOne insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [itemOne.asset duration]) ofTrack:videoAssetTrackOne atTime:startTime error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error inserting track into composition %@", error);
    }

    [audioTrackOne insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [itemOne.asset duration]) ofTrack:audioAssetTrackOne atTime:startTime error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error inserting track into composition %@", error);
    }


    for (int i = 1; i < ([playerItems count]); i++) {

        AVPlayerItem *itemTwo = playerItems[i];

        CMTime nextTransitionTime = CMTimeSubtract(CMTimeAdd(startTime, [itemOne.asset duration]), transitionDuration);
        CMTimeRange currentTransitionRange = CMTimeRangeMake(nextTransitionTime, transitionDuration);

        AVAsset *videoAssetTwo = [itemTwo asset];

        AVAssetTrack *videoAssetTrackTwo = [videoAssetTwo tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo][0];
        AVAssetTrack *audioAssetTrackTwo = [videoAssetTwo tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio][0];

        AVMutableCompositionTrack *trackTwo = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

        AVMutableCompositionTrack *audioTrackTwo = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

        [trackTwo insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [itemTwo.asset duration]) ofTrack:videoAssetTrackTwo atTime:nextTransitionTime error:&error];
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error inserting track into composition %@", error);
        }

        [audioTrackTwo insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [itemTwo.asset duration]) ofTrack:audioAssetTrackTwo atTime:nextTransitionTime error:&error];
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error inserting track into composition %@", error);
        }

        AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *transition = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];

        AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *from = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:trackOne];
        //[from setOpacityRampFromStartOpacity:1.0 toEndOpacity:0.0 timeRange:currentTransitionRange];

        AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *to = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:trackTwo];
      [to setOpacityRampFromStartOpacity:0.0 toEndOpacity:1.0 timeRange:currentTransitionRange];

      transition.backgroundColor = [[NSColor clearColor] CGColor];

      CMTimeRange timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(100000, 600));
      transition.timeRange = timeRange;

      transition.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:to, from, nil];
      [transitions addObject:transition];

        startTime = nextTransitionTime;
        itemOne = itemTwo;
        videoAssetOne = videoAssetTwo;
        videoAssetTrackOne = videoAssetTrackTwo;
        audioAssetTrackOne = audioAssetTrackTwo;
        trackOne = trackTwo;
        audioTrackOne = audioTrackTwo;
    }

  videoComposition.instructions = transitions;
  videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 24);
  videoComposition.renderSize = composition.naturalSize; // CGSizeMake(480, 360);

  AVPlayerItem *item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:composition];
  item.videoComposition = videoComposition;

  return item;
}
```